# Spring создание компонентов

Tags: java, spring, компоненты

слышал что в спринге создание классов помеченных @Component через ключевое слово new является плохой практикой, но так и не смог найти объяснения, почему это плохая практика. Подскажите пожалуйста что почитать или объясните почему это плоххая практика?

Comment: Потому что созданием этого компонента управляет Spring, вам нужно всего лишь инжектировать этот компонент в свой класс.

Comment: Не рекомендуется копать землю руками, если у вас есть при себе лопата. По той же причине не рекомендуется вручную создавать компоненты, если у вас в проекте spring

Comment: Тут можно много спорить, какая практика хорошая, а какая плохая  и поэтому невозможно дать объективный ответ. Прямой ответ зависит от того как вы используете созданный обьект в контексте или без него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что одной из обязанностью-возможностью Spring  это Dependency Injection или говоря по-нашему, внедрение зависимостей. Поэтому вам только остается корректно настроить что от чего зависит (при помощи аннотаций, конфигурационных классов или xml), а остальное за Вас сделает Spring (создаст объекты и передаст ссылки на них другим зависимым объектам). А если вы какие-то компоненты будете создавать вручную, то Spring о них знать не будет, он будет создавать свой объект и манипулировать им. А оно как минимум не логично. Как-то так.